# Are diamonds with question marks normal in a encrypted message?

Tags: java, encryption, character, aes

[results_screenshot_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as3lT.png)

```
byte[] originalMessage = MESSAGE.getBytes();
System.out.println("Byte[]: " + Arrays.toString(originalMessage));
System.out.println("Original: " + MESSAGE);
EnDat newEncryption = new EnDat(KEY);
byte[] encryptedTemp = newEncryption.getEncryptMessage(originalMessage);
System.out.println("Byte[]: " + Arrays.toString(encryptedTemp));
System.out.println("Encrypted: " + new String(encryptedTemp,0,encryptedTemp.length,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] decryptedTemp = newEncryption.getDecryptMessage(encryptedTemp);
System.out.println("Byte[]: " + Arrays.toString(decryptedTemp));
System.out.println("Decrypted: " + new String(decryptedTemp,0,decryptedTemp.length,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

---

```
public byte[] getEncryptMessage(byte[] msg) throws Exception {
    if(DEBUG_MODE) System.out.println(">>>ADDRESS: " + msg );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyVal, ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(msg);
}
```

---

```
public byte[] getDecryptMessage(byte[] encryptedMsg) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyVal, ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    if(DEBUG_MODE) System.out.println(">>>ADDRESS: " + encryptedMsg );
    return cipher.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
}
```

I have done little encryption before, so I tried with Java's Cipher class, it turned out that everything works fine except the encrypted message turned out to have characters that look like diamonds with question marks in them(which had negative char values). Is it normal for encryption, or is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Those are encrypted characters which are not able to be read by the compiler which you use !

Comment: This is just an encoding thing, nothing to worry about it you're sure your code is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of encryption is *supposed* to look like random garbage. If it's legible then someone either tweaked it to look that way (say with BASE64 encoding) or something has gone wrong.

Also, the output is a binary stream. It's not meant to be converted to a `String` or printed, because it's not text.

So this line:

```
new String(encryptedTemp,0,encryptedTemp.length,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Is taking the encrypted data and tries to interpret it as UTF-8 text. But it is not UTF-8 text so you'll get weird output.

Comment: Yeah, sure, since the number is negative. Thx!

Comment: @G.Martin: it's not just the negative numbers (in fact "negative numbers" are just a result of interpreting the bits in some way and aren't really an inherent property of the byte stream either). It's more general than that: interpreting stuff that's not meant to be text as text is problematic. Try opening a JPG file with a text editor and you'll see similar garbage (though with slightly more structure). Any "binary file" will look similar to this in that it will not contain readable text and probably some "wrong characters".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal behaviour.

Java uses Unicode as encoding for printing characters. When you encrypt a message, it is encrypted at the *binary* level, not at the *"valid-character"* level. This means, it is possible (and common) for encrypted data to contain non-character values. When you try to print them, you get a �-symbol, which is..

> used to replace an unknown, unrecognized or unrepresentable character

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block))

---

If you still want to view the encrypted data, you can do so by saving the data to a file (for example using `java.io.FileOutputStream`), and then opening it with a program capable of showing binary or hexadecimal values.
I recommend [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/). It automatically recognizes binary files and displays them as such.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pathname");
fos.write(encryptedByteArray);
```